# What are the start and end times of a pandas.Period() object? What role does the parameter 'freq' play in the Period object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, period

Suppose a Period object is created in Pandas as -

```
In [1]: pd.Period('2021', 'M')
Out [1]: Period('2021-01', 'M')
```

What are the **start and end points** of this period object? How does the frequency *M* affect those start and end points? In fact, what role does this frequency play here?

Comment: it is fully documented... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.html

Comment: To be fair, that documentation does not really explain what is meant by 'frequency'. Normally, a perdiod of time has a duration, and frequency is the inverse of the duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `freq` specifies the length of the period, is it a daily period or monthly period? etc.. For example if you pass a date `2021-03-21` with a `D` frequency

```
import pandas as pd
period = pd.Period('2021-03-21', 'D')
```

then one can know when does the period starts and end by calling the the `start_time` and `end_time` attributes

```
period.start_time
>>> Timestamp('2021-03-21 00:00:00')
period.end_time
>>> Timestamp('2021-03-21 23:59:59.999999999')
```

Now, consider the whole month of March, a frequency `M` is a Monthly period

```
period = pd.Period('2021-03-21', 'M')
period.start_time
>>> Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00')
period.end_time
>>> Timestamp('2021-03-31 23:59:59.999999999')
```